# Applying for company B after accepting contract at company A but have not yet started

Tags: united-kingdom, contracts

This is based in the UK.

I accepted an offer a while ago to start at company A next year, but am currently interviewing at a different company B which I'd rather work for. I have not yet told company B this and I'm wondering what my best steps are.

I'm concerned that if company B gave me an offer and I then gave my notice in to company A, that company B may rescind the offer on the grounds that I had an accepted offer at company A and then gave my notice in (which I assume they would find out during a background check). I don't want to be left in a situation with no offer at all.

I should mention that I interned at company A which means they are one of my previous employers.

What should I do here?

Comment: @Anketam I should have mentioned it's in the UK

Comment: Most companies are just looking out for themselves. Company B is getting the better end of the deal at the expense of company A. I have yet to experience a business that would lose an opportunity to make money (they're not hiring you as a act of charity) based on perceived fairness with a competitor.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question

> I accepted an offer a while ago to start at company A next year, but
> am currently interviewing at a different company B which I'd rather
> work for. I have not yet told company B this and I'm wondering what my
> best steps are.

and on the timing as stated in your question and the comment:

> The contract for A says the probation period starts from employment,
> so I'm not even there yet - I'm assuming that should also be okay?

There is no need to tell company B you have accepted another offer.

Before you start with company A, it is ok to apply, interview, and negotiate with other companies. In fact I encourage people to keep looking. Unless the contract with Company A awards you damages if they don't hire you, there is always a chance that you might never start with company A, and find yourself with no job. Keeping the search going protects you if that happens.

Unless the contract you signed dictates damages you would have to pay, there is little company A can do if you decide to accept another offer.

> I'm concerned that if company B gave me an offer and I then gave my
> notice in to company A, that company B may rescind the offer on the
> grounds that I had an accepted offer at company A and then gave my
> notice in (which I assume they would find out during a background
> check). I don't want to be left in a situation with no offer at all.

Because you haven't started with company A, there is nothing to tell company B. There is nothing for them to discover.

Now if the offer from company B comes after you start at company A, you do have to worry about notice periods, probation periods, and the like. If you start with company A, then you will have to tell company B if they ask you to list all employment on a background check form. They also may have to be told if they think you are unemployed, but wonder why you can't start tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Something I forgot to mention here was that I interned at company A which means they are one of my previous employers, so could they find out about the offer upon background check?

Answer (score 0):

So long as it's within the probation period it's not a big deal, it's a bit worse if it's over the probation period, but not much. There is no requirement for a person to be unemployed when applying for positions.

It's not a great look, but it shouldn't be a showstopper.

Comment: The contract for A says the probation period starts from employment, so I'm not even there yet - I'm assuming that should also be okay?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. I once cancelled an accepted offer just because it started too late and I wanted to be earning earlier. It happens. You need to look after yourself first.